Setting Calendar Event with Azure Function
Using Visual Studio 2022 and c# needed to create Azure Function that creates an event in the calendar.
Followed this guide to configure the workload identity federation for Azure. Created a Service Account and connected it to the function. Created Azure Function that authenticates with Google Cloud and then creates calendar events. Tried this method with a service account using a regular VS application and it worked, so all the permissions for the calendar should be fine. When using Azure Function nothing happens but the deploy and publish are fine. Added some logs to maybe understand where the problem is but on Azure Portal couldn't see any of those(idk why).
this is the code: -
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace setEvent
{
    public class babam
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public babam(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<babam>();
        }

        [Function("babam")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Получение учетных данных сервисного аккаунта.");
                // Инициализируем учетные данные сервисного аккаунта.
                GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()
                .CreateScoped(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);

                // Создаем сервис для доступа к API Календаря.
                _logger.LogInformation("Создание сервиса для доступа к API Календаря.");
                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Calendar API .NET Quickstart"
                });
                string calendarId = "36e41687bff738ba3c57426d98d17a37e604fa99485a38d1c18cc2f1e8225114@group.calendar.google.com";
                var newEvent = new Event
                {
                    Summary = "New event",
                    Location = "Haifa",
                    Start = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-04-30T09:00:00+02:00"),
                        TimeZone = "Asia/Jerusalem",
                    },
                    End = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-04-30T10:00:00+02:00"),
                        TimeZone = "Asia/Jerusalem",
                    },
                };

                // Выполняем запрос к API Календаря.
                var createdEvent = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId).Execute();
                _logger.LogInformation("Событие успешно создан.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Произошла ошибка при создании события.");
            }
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!!!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}



no exceptions, response, log messages on Azure Functions running on Azure?

Going "MyFunction" -> Monitor -> (At Invokations I see function being invoked) -> Logs ("Connected!") only, nothing but this

In your code you were not providing proper credentials.
This code worked for me
For reference check this document.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Google.Apis.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;


namespace calenderevent
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

             string[] scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
             string AppName = "calenderdotnet";


            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credstorePath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credstorePath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credstorePath);
            }

            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = AppName,
            });

            // create events.
            var newEvent = new Event
            {
                Summary = "New event",
                Location = "Haifa",
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-04-30T09:00:00+02:00"),
                    TimeZone = "Asia/Jerusalem",
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-04-30T10:00:00+02:00"),
                    TimeZone = "Asia/Jerusalem",
                },
            };

            var createevent = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary").Execute();
            _logger.LogInformation($"calender event created{createevent.HtmlLink}");


            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}


Note: CalenderId will always be primary.

OUTPUT



